# Cannot find module '../lib/tsc.js' when releasing typescript application to azure

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, npm, azure-devops

I'm trying to release a typescript application to a Azure App Service running on Linux. I'm doing this using Azure DevOps. I've setup a build and release pipeline which succeed, but when I visit the URL of my app service, I see a message saying ":c Application Error" and it refers to the diagnostic logs. These logs give me the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '../lib/tsc.js'

**Full Error Log**

```
myApp@1.0.0 prod /home/site/wwwroot
> npm run build && npm run start
> myApp@1.0.0 build /home/site/wwwroot
> tsc
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/tsc.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/tsc:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myApp@1.0.0 build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

My Azure Devops environment cosists of build pipeline which performs a npm install and publishes that to an artifact and a release pipeline which performs a deploy and then runs a start command. These steps succeed and the start command is ran, but it creates the above errors.

I've tried building the application before creating the artifact, but this gave errors in the build step where it couldn't find files that were being imported. I can run the **npm run prod** command without any issues localy.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

**Package.json**

```
{
"name": "MyApp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
"start": "nodemon ./dist/index.js",
"prod": "npm run build && npm run start",
"test": "mocha --ui tdd -r ts-node/register tests/**/*.test.ts"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "@google/chatbase": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.7.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "ssml-builder": "^0.4.3",
    "ts-sinon": "^1.0.17",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "tsc-watch": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
    },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4"
}
}
```

**Tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "pretty": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es6",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
},
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "src/data/*.json",
  "src/data/sounds/*.mp3"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
]
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Faced the same issue due to copying `node_modules`.

**SOLUTION**

The following change in `package.json` solves the issue:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc", // not just "tsc"
  ...
}
```

**DESCRIPTION**

There is an original tsc script placed at `node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc`, but there is a symlink to this file placed at `node_modules/.bin/tsc`.

While the `node_modules/.bin/tsc` is symlink, importing `../lib/tsc.js` works properly, but after copying this is just a file with same content, so the copying is breaking this importing by relative path.

So specifying the path to original tsc script solves this issue.

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: Yeah, this is correct.  Zipping up `node_modules` without preserving the symlinks and then uploading that to the build-pipeline got me here.

Comment: Nope, just got an error -- '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Nando I am getting the same error, did you fix that

Comment: @Nando @Arnab Bhattacharya are you trying this build on local srver or azure cloud? you might need to try  `"build": "tsc || ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",`

Comment: I had this problem today while deploying a function to Digital Ocean - it first returned an error on rollup, but after reverting to using just plain old tsc it started giving an error on tsc, then I know it was no coincidence. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 6):

SOLVED

```
rm -rf your_project/node_modules
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: This worked for me (with the adding of reinstalling my Node dependences). I believe the error is that something went wrong with the node_modules installation. I would definitely recommend this over this accepted answer because there might be other issues in node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **tsc** command to compile your typescript file, for this way, it won't include necessary packages' code to the result file (js), so you need to upload/publish **node_modules** folder (include package files) to **/home/site/wwwroot** too (can publish **node_modules** with result file through release together).

You can compile your typescript file through webpack, which can include packages' code to the result file. https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: This did seem like a promising solution, but in my case ended up with having to fix every import in my project to resolve a list of errors when using webpack. This didn't seem very maintainable so I didn't implement it any further.

Comment: @Jordi You can upload node_modules folder to wwwroot. Or you can try to include package.json during deployment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps#using-a-packagejson-file

Comment: @Jordi There is a blog about deploying nodejs project and check node_modules: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2015/12/01/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-site-into-azure-web-app-to-create-a-website/

Comment: So the node_module being missing was indeed the issue. After some struggeling in Azure DevOps I managed to get the files together with the dist. It was still giving some troubles because I was forcing the application onto a specific port number, but after I let azure decide the port number, the application started running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with:

```
"build": "tsc || ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
```

The `tsc` works on my machine, then the second command is not executed.

On Azure, the `tsc` fails, then the second command `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc` is executed and works.

Comment: `tsc` doesn't fail in azure cloud

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA The original question reports failure, and in my scenario it also fails

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue and solved it by updating the npm to appropriate version(Compatible with installed nodejs version) and deleted all node modules and then did "sudo npm install typescript -g" and "npm install"

Comment: Do NOT use `sudo` to make your `npm install` work correctly. This just leads to more problems that then require the use of `sudo`. And believeme, you don't want open source packages being able to run their postinstall scripts as sudo. Instead, use `chown` to take possession of the `~/.npm` folder, and any other cache, temporary, or binary folders used by npm.